How to composite frames after rendering has completed?
I am trying to render an 8,112 frame animation at 4K 60FPS with Blender, using the compositor to add some post-process effects such as chromatic aberration.
When I begin rendering, it renders and composites each frame one-by-one, which causes the compositor to initialize and de-initialize every single rendered frame, which increases my per-frame render time by over double what it is without the compositor.
Is there a way to make the frames render first, then composite all of the frames after rendering has completed, such that the compositor only has to initialize once and de-initialize once? As the initialization sequence takes a lot more time than actually compositing the image.
For reference, my project is EEVEE, with the export format set to FFmpeg (Matroska Container, H.264 Codec), if that helps with my issue.
